# Torque of a lever with two fixed points at an acute angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, torque

[image: Diagram of a weight attached to a base with an arm extending out from the base then returning at an acute angle before terminating at the weight.]

Is the torque at the yellow fixed point calculated using the perpendicular distance between the yellow fixed point and the red weight, or using the distance between the yellow fixed point and the blue fixed point?

Comment: Hinges imply the arms are free to rotate. Are you sure the arms are free to rotate? Or are the yellow and blue points just that (points) that keep the horizontal and angled arm at the same position?

Comment: Sorry, they are "points".

Comment: In that case, just imagine that the thin triangular space between the horizontal part and the angled part were joined by a rigid plate of negligible mass. Then you'd have just one arm of a weird shape, with a load applied some way along it. Now mentally remove the rigid plate; you still have one arm of a weird shape, since the blue circle is a rigid joint.

Comment: Yellow and red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rigid body like the one you have diagrammed, to calculate the torque applied around some pivot you always use the the perpendicular distance from the force to the pivot. In this case, it is the distance you have marked in green. This distance is often called the "Moment Arm", or "Lever Arm", and can be seen in the picture below.

[image: Lever Arm of a wrench]

If you are familiar with vector operations, this is due to the fact that torque $\vec{\tau}$ is equal the cross product between the force vector $\vec{F}$ and the vector pointing from the pivot to the location the force is applied $\vec{r}$ (in our case, $\vec{r}$ would point from the yellow circle to the red triangle). **This cross product increases when there is an increase in distance between the Force and pivot which is at a right angle to the direction the force is being applied**. If the force is moved further away from the pivot in the direction in which the force is pointing (in our case this would mean shifting the location of the red triangle in the vertical direction), there is no change in the torque.

All of these considerations are irrespective of the shape of the object on which this force is acting: as long as it is rigid these dynamics are the same.

---

By the way, this is exactly why those fun [balancing dragonfly toys](https://img.kwcdn.com/product/Fancyalgo/VirtualModelMatting/c59c024eefccc5b4688388c815b41c8c.jpg?imageMogr2/auto-orient%7CimageView2/2/w/1300/q/80/format/webp) work. While their shape would make you think that there is a large lop-lopsidedness of their weight (more or less the entire body is projected off to one side of the point of contact), there is enough weight in the tips of the wings which extend forwards to allow for the center of mass to be below the pivot point. This means that it is in a stable configuration while sitting on it's nose, regardless of the strangeness of it's shape.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 